# Measuring/Calculating Distance in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, mapping, camera

I need to calculate the distance between two points in iOS. I can guarantee at least an iPhone 4 so the picture quality on the camera should be good. The idea is to calculate the distance to a point using the picture. There's an app called easyMeasure which does exactly what I need to do.

I'm ok with Pythagoras but this boggles my mind. How would I do something like this?

Comment: In addition to easyLevel, there's also http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/site-survey/id357934015?mt=8 . I understand the technology but am I just looking for the inverse sine or would it be best to get some kind of hardware device for the phone?

Comment: I believe I have a solution that will work, but it may require some visual demonstration. I should have an answer in a few hours that I can create once I'm home. I get out of school at ~7 EST, so maybe 8:30-9 I'll try to have an answer up?

Comment: @Echilon have you done . Can you help me how it done. I have to do similar thing

Comment: @Echilon Can you please post the solution which you have used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so you were correct in that you need to use sine and such. First though, you'll need to find the lens angle of the iPhones camera. Do do this, put the camera a known distance away from the wall and measure how far it is from the edge of the field of vision to the other side and divide by two. To find θ in the picture below, use tanθ = opposite/adjacent, so inverse tan(opposite/adjacent) = θ.

[image: Picture 2]

Once you know that, you just have the user take a picture, and give a measurement for how big something on the screen really is. Then just use tanθ = opposite/adjacent, and since you now know θ and the opposite distance, adjacent = opposite/tanθ.

[image: Picture 1]

Hope that helps!

Comment: I do believe that'll do what I need. Thanks!

Comment: i want to calculate the distance between two point from iPhone camera. i am explain you  that what i want. Suppose i am standing with my iPhone (with camera on) 10 feet far from the object. So my two objects are 10 feet far from me (camera).
Now i want o calculate the distance between that two object which is 10 feet far from camera .These two object are on the straight line . So how can i calculate the distance between two point ?

Answer (score 0):

New update in ios7
    @import CoreLocation;
    @import MapKit;

```
CLLocation *sanFrancisco = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:37.775 longitude:-122.4183333];
CLLocation *portland = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:45.5236111 longitude:-122.675];
CLLocationDistance distance = [portland distanceFromLocation:sanFrancisco];

MKDistanceFormatter *formatter = [[MKDistanceFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.units = MKDistanceFormatterUnitsImperial;
NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromDistance:distance]); // 535 miles
```