# How to find the actual distance between iphone camera and an object placed in wall in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, augmented-reality

I am new to iOS development. I need to know how to find the distance between an object and the iPhone camera. I have referenced many sources, but I have not got the appropriate result.
Any good tutorials or sample source code are appreciated.

I am doing an Augmented Reality project and need to find the distance between the object and the iPhone camera which is capturing the images.

Comment: It might be useful to specify which resources you have tried.

Comment: May below links help you.

1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22634518/how-to-get-distance-of-object-from-iphone-camera-using-image-exif-meta-data
2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600103/measure-distance-from-iphone-camera-to-an-object-using-camera
3. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7728553/measuring-calculating-distance-in-ios

Comment: Thank you for the great answers and support...

Comment: @Steve Wilford: Actually I have an image tracking project. Image is tracking smoothly, but i need to get the distance between that image which placed in wall and the camera. CVSDK is used for image tracking.